# Prove that if $m\mid z$ implies that $n \mid z$, then $n\mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to prove the following divisibility fact:

> For any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, suppose $m \mid z$ implies that $n \mid z$. Then $n \mid m$.

The intuition here is not too difficult for me to grasp. If, for example, some $z$ always has a factor of $m$ implies that it always has a factor of $n$, that would suggest we can take a factor of $n$ out of $m$. I am having some difficult proving this fact rigorously, though.

A hint on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Is contradiction the appropriate approach?

Comment: Well, noting that $m\,|\,m$ might help.

Comment: That is certainly true, but I do not see how we can use it.

Comment: Just apply the statement using $z=m$.

Comment: Are we allowed to do that, though, when we want to prove this fact for all $z$?

Comment: You are told that $m,n$ are such that, no matter what $z$ is, $m\,|\,z\implies n\,|\,z$.  That is given.  Given that this is true you are asked to deduce that $n\,|\m$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set $z=m$. Clearly $m \mid m$. We have:
$$n \mid z  \implies n \mid m$$
Done!

BTW we can substitute $z=m$ since the condition is:
$$m \mid z \implies n \mid z$$
for any $z$.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearer in terms of *sets* of multiples, where **divides = contains** by $\,(\color{#c00}{3\!\iff\! 2})\,$ below. The utility of this view becomes clear when one studies (principal) ideals or (cyclic) groups.

**Lemma** $ $ TFAE for $\,m,n\in\Bbb Z$

$(1)\ \ \, n\:\!|\:\!z\,\Leftarrow\, m\:\!|\:\!z,\ $ for all $\,z\in\Bbb Z$

$\!\left.\begin{align}&\color{#c00}{(2)}\ \ \ \ n\Bbb Z\,\supseteq\, m\Bbb Z\\[.5em]
&\color{#c00}{(3)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \  n\,\mid\, m\end{align}\,\right\}\ $  **[divides = contains]**

**Proof** $\ \ (1\Rightarrow 2)\,\ \ z\in m\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,m\mid z\Rightarrow\,n\mid z\,\Rightarrow\, z\in n\Bbb Z$
 $(2\Rightarrow 3)^{\phantom{|^|}}\ \ m\in m\Bbb Z\subseteq n\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, m\in m\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,m = nz\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid m.\,$
$(3\Rightarrow 1)^{\phantom{|^|}}\ \ n\mid m\mid z\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid z\ $ by transitivity of "divides".